# Apply Spring ModelAttribute to all controllers that use a specific parameter type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a SpringBoot REST application I have a `TableRequest` type that contains column sorting, filtering, and paging details for GET requests for tabular data.  It's generic in that it doesn't care what the specific data being requested is, it only specifies generic table parameters.  As such it's applicable across many different controller methods.  Also, because it applies to GET requests the fields are passed as request parameters (no `@RequestBody` json parameter).  I've got a `@ModelAttribute` method inside the controller class that parses the request parameters into a `TableRequest` object, then the actual `@RequestMapping` method receives that object as a `@ModelAttribute` parameter.

Because the `TableRequest` class is generic, I'd like to be able to use it across multiple controllers without having to copy the parsing logic into every one. I'm wondering if there's a Spring-y annotation-based way of reusing the same `@ModelAttribute` method any time a controller has a `TableRequest` input parameter.

Thanks in advance :)

---

**My Solution** (based on selected answer below)

I created a `@TableRequestController` annotation and a corresponding `@ControllerAdvice` class that applies only to controller classes that have that annotation.  That ControllerAdvice class includes the `@ModelAttribute` method tht parses the GET request parameters into a `TableRequest` object.

The one important caveat here is that the new `@TableRequestController` may only be applied to Controller class as a whole, not to individual controller methods. As such, I created a separate inner controller class, tagged with that annotation, whose @RequestMapping methods all accept a TableRequest object.

@TableRequestController:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface TableRequestController {}
```

ControllerAdvice class:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = TableRequestController.class)
public class TableRequestControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public TableRequest tableRequest(
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> params,
            @RequestParam int pageStart,
            @RequestParam int pageSize) {

        return new TableRequest(params, pageStart, pageSize);
    }
}
```

TableRequest REST controller class:

```
@RestController
@TableRequestController
public static class MyTableRequestController {

    @RequestMapping("/the/table/request/url")
    public MyResponse makeTableRequest(
            TableRequest tableRequest) {

        return new MyResponse(tableRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@ControllerAdvice`. Everything defined here applies to all controllers, or a defined subset, if you prefer that.

[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-controller-advice)

Another alternative (better imho) is to write a [message converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-message-converters). It only handles one specific type. You no longer need `@ModelAttribute` but simply have a `TableRequest` parameter in you controller method.

Comment: I tried putting the ModelAttribute method in a ControllerAdvice class but that caused all other controllers to break because it was trying to parse the TableRequest params, even on controllers that didn't use it.  Is there some way of indicating that the ModelAttribute only applies to RequestParameters of a given type?

Comment: Reading & thinking a bit more perhaps the right thing to do is to create a `TableRequestController` interface and target the ControllerAdvice to that

Comment: @pedorro I added an alternative solution.

Comment: I like your idea of using a MessageConverter, but I don't see where I can access the request parameters from one.  They all seem to be focused on reading the request body in some way or another.

Comment: @pedorro You should be able to cast the `HttpInputMessage` to an `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: I'm pretty confident at this point that the `MessageConverter` option will not work in this case.  It really seems to apply only to @RequestBody parameters, such as can be submitted via POST.  The whole point here is that I'm implementing a GET request. That said, I think I've finally settled on a working solution based on your initial suggestion of targeting a `@ControllerAdvice` at a specific subset of controllers. My full solution is included as an update to my original question.

Comment: @pedorro Of course, I missed the `GET` part. Message converters for `GET` requests used to work with older versions of Spring, but stopped working with 4.1 or 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

> In a SpringBoot REST application I have a TableRequest type that
>   contains column sorting, filtering, and paging details for GET
>   requests for tabular data. It's generic in that it doesn't care what the specific data being requested is, it only specifies generic table parameters

**This means what you have is a utility service.**

So define the class as service and access it inside the views.

Access any beans in your application context using SpringEL’s syntax: `${@myBean.doSomething()}`