# Object exists and can be used on JSP page but I don't know WHY it works

Tags: java, spring, jsp

alright so this is a bit tricky to explain well but I will do my best and hopefully someone has an idea.

So this project in built using the Spring Framework. I did not write this code but a previous dev who is no longer here.

here is a snippet from the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/affidavit/{id}/{userid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getProgramAffidavit(@PathVariable("id") 
Program program, @PathVariable("userid")Attendee attendee, Model model) {

model.addAttribute("affidavitDetailDtoTest",affidavitDetailDto);

return "affidavit/program_affidavit";
}
```

I won't bother with the code that constructs the affidavitDetailDto object for now as I don't think it is relevant.

so you will see that this adds an attribute called affidavitDetailDTO to the model.

then over on my view page which is a jsp page I have a form with a model attribute of "affidavitDetailDTO" and my related information.

so now is the part I don't understand. I click the 'submit' button and my page and the form posts and calls the following controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/affidavit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(AffidavitDetailDto affidavitDetail, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {

    String out;

    if(request.getParameter("programID")!= null)
        out = request.getParameter("programID");
    else
        return "redirect: " + request.getContextPath()+ "/home";

    //Session Information Section

    //gets a list of program sessions and assigns it to affidavitProgramSessions dto list
    List<AffidavitProgramSessionDto> affidavitProgramSessions = affidavitDetail.getAffProgramSessionList();

    //Iterates through list of session in affidavitProgramSessions
    for (Iterator<AffidavitProgramSessionDto> iter = affidavitProgramSessions.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ){

        //create  AffidavitProgramSession DTO object and fill it with value from list
        AffidavitProgramSessionDto session = iter.next();

        //get the programs session ID and assign it to a string
        String programSessionDetailId = session.getProgramSessionDetailId();

        logger.debug("programSessionDetailId:: " + programSessionDetailId);

        //if there was no program session id then remove the item from list
        if(StringUtil.isBlank(programSessionDetailId)) {
            iter.remove();
        }else{
            // set the program session detail from value in the program session detail repo found by program session ID
            session.setProgramSessionDetail(psdRepo.findOne(UUID.fromString(programSessionDetailId)));
        }
    }

    //End oF Session Information Section

    out = "affidavit/summary";

    return out;
}
```

now on the summary jsp page there is the following loop to spit out the results.

```
c:forEach items="${affidavitDetailDto.affProgramSessionList}" var="session">
```

so here is my issues.. how the hell is it working. where is that affidavitDetailDto object coming from?

it isn't the GET method in the controller adding it because I can rename the attribute and the summary page still works.

any ideas?

### EDIT

Showing how affidavitDetailDto is created in controller.

in the class this is done

```
@Controller
public class AffidavitController extends BaseController   {

private AffidavitDetailDto affidavitDetailDto;
```

then in the GET Request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/affidavit/{id}/{userid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getProgramAffidavit(@PathVariable("id") Program program, @PathVariable("userid")Attendee attendee, Model model) {


affidavitDetailDto = new AffidavitDetailDto();

List<AffidavitProgramSessionDto> affProgramSessionList = affidavitDetailDto.getAffProgramSessionList();
    Set<ProgramSessionDetail> programSessionDetails = ps.getProgramSessionDetail();
    if(programSessionDetails != null) {
        for (ProgramSessionDetail programSessionDetail : programSessionDetails) {
            AffidavitProgramSessionDto affidavitProgramSessionDto = new AffidavitProgramSessionDto();
            AffidavitAttendeeTypeDetailDto affidavitAttendeeTypeDetailDto = new AffidavitAttendeeTypeDetailDto();
            affidavitProgramSessionDto.setAffidavitAttendeeTypeDetailDto(affidavitAttendeeTypeDetailDto);
            affProgramSessionList.add(affidavitProgramSessionDto);
        }
    }


    model.addAttribute("affidavitDetailDto",affidavitDetailDto);
```

Also on the model attribute level.

```
@ModelAttribute
private void addAttributes(Model model) {

    logger.debug("call addAttributes.....");
    if(affidavitDetailDto != null && affidavitDetailDto.getAffProgramSessionList().size() != 0) {
        logger.debug("add affidavitDetailDto to model......");
        model.addAttribute("affidavitDetailDto", affidavitDetailDto);
    }
```

If I change the line
    model.addAttribute("affidavitDetailDto", affidavitDetailDto);

to be something like

```
model.addAttribute("testing1234", affidavitDetailDto);
```

then the affidavitDetailDto objects STILL work on the summary post page.

### Edit 2

This is the form tag that the for each loop runs in.

```
<form:form acceptCharset="utf-8" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${CTX_PATH}/approvedProgram" modelAttribute="affidavitDetailDto" id="jpFormInput">
```

however.. I can change the modelAtttrbute to equal "Madeupnothing123" and the jsp page still functions as normal.. this is why I am so confused.

Comment: if you can provide me the code in github, I would be happy to findout

Comment: I believe the way how affidavitDetailDto is constructed does matter. I have two ideas: either it is a `@SessionAttrubute` or a singleton `@Component`. One item that is strange is that model attribute name is `affidavitDetailDtoTest` while your expression has it without Test postfix `items="${affidavitDetailDto.affProgramSessionList}"`

Comment: my bad. that "affidavitDetailDtoTest' was from my demonstrating to a co-worker how that attribute name seemed to have zero relation to the summary page.  as in I can name that attribute anything I want yet on the view page  affidavitDetailDto.attributeName  still works.

Comment: added some addtional code if that helps for trouble shooting.

Comment: Maybe you will find something usefull on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155890/apply-spring-modelattribute-to-all-controllers-that-use-a-specific-parameter-typ
Are ther any annotations on `BaseController` class?

Comment: Looks like affidavitDetailDto is fetched from session and not the request in your JSP.  Check where Spring is adding the AffidavitDetailDto into the session. It  is most likely due to @SessionAttrubute as mentioned by previous comment.

Comment: Can you share your form tag where your c:forEach items="${affidavitDetailDto.affProgramSessionList}" var="session"> code is present?

Comment: try changing your class name AffidavitDetailDto to something as sampledetailsdto, I am pretty sure it will break your summary jsp, I dont know from which exact version but spring creates model attributes with same name as classname.

Comment: In reply to  Amit K bist.  I have added the code above

Comment: I have renamed the class and it broke the page as expected.. so yeah it looks like somehow it is creating an object some wheres with the name of the class?  I don't see anything in code accomplishing this though.

Comment: Also I have found no session attributes in the controller code